# Laravel website randomly starting spitting 419 Paged expired when register or log in is used

Tags: laravel

So i have a laravel site and it worked fine now when trying to register or log in it shows 419 page expired and i have not changed anything in the code.

I have a @csrf in the code already and tried seeing if there's something wrong with it and changed it around a little but to no avail. As i said it worked before which is why i am confused

(I have already tried clearing browser cache and `php artisan cache:clear`.

[what is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uXIu.png)

Comment: Are any cookies involved? We had a 419 caused by a duplicate cookie entry, one of which was invalid. Clearing the two cookies, and relogin cleared the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

First enter the following command:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Then add the following value in the first part of your form:

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

or

```
@csrf
```

Error 419 should be fixed.